# Speed up query: ORDER BY with LIMIT (indexing?)

Tags: mysql, performance, perl, sorting

I am trying to find the closest gene, given position information, from a gene table. Here is an example:

> `SELECT chrom, txStart, txEnd, name2, strand FROM
>   wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 WHERE chrom = 'chr1' AND txStart < 713885 AND
>   strand = '+' ORDER BY txStart DESC LIMIT 1;`

My test runs have been pretty slow, which is problematic.

Here is an `EXPLAIN` output with default indexing (by `chrom`):

> `| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len |   ref   | rows  | Extra |`
>   `| 1 | SIMPLE | wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 | ref  |  chrom | chrom | 257 | const | 15843 | Using where; Using filesort |`

Filesort is used and is probably causing all the sluggishness?

I tried speeding up the sorting by indexing `(chrom, txStart, strand)`, or just `txStart` alone, but it only got slower (?). My reasoning is that `txStart` is not selective enough to be a good index, and that a whole-table scanning in this case is actually faster?

Here is the `EXPLAIN` output with the additional indexing:

> `| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |`
>   `| 1 | SIMPLE | wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 | range | chrom,closest_gene_lookup | closest_gene_lookup | 261 | NULL | 57 | Using where |`
>
> `| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |`
>   `|  1 | SIMPLE | wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 | range | chrom,txStart | txStart | 4  | NULL | 1571 | Using where |`

**Table structure**

> `CREATE TABLE`wgEncodeGencodeCompV12`(`
>
>   bin`smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   name`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
>
>   chrom`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
>
>   strand`char(1) NOT NULL,`
>
>   txStart`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   txEnd`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   cdsStart`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   cdsEnd`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   exonCount`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
>
>   exonStarts`longblob NOT NULL,`
>
>   exonEnds`longblob NOT NULL,`
>
>   score`int(11) default NULL,`
>
>   name2`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
>
>   cdsStartStat`enum('none','unk','incmpl','cmpl') NOT NULL,`
>
>   cdsEndStat`enum('none','unk','incmpl','cmpl') NOT NULL,`
>
>   exonFrames`longblob NOT NULL,
>
>     KEY`chrom`(`chrom`,`bin`),
>
>     KEY`name`(`name`),
>
>     KEY`name2`(`name2`)
>
>   )`

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I appreciate your time!

**(update)Solution:**
Combining both commenters' suggestions significantly improved run time.

Comment: Please provide some statistics: what is the typical number of rows at all and what are typical distributions of `chrom`, `strand`, `txStart` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for commenting -- there are ~170,000 rows. `chrom` is a varchar, some examples of which are "chr1", "chr2", ..., up to "chrX" and "chrY". `strand` is either "+" or "-". `txStart` ranges from a few thousands to billions, and I belive they are all unique. I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (query on a single table, no joins, no complicated stuff) it is important to understand the distribution of values in each column, and to understand how the database server utilizes the indexes. When you have a field with a rather big range of different values, then that one should be used for indexing. (e.g. an index on `strand` would just split the whole data in `+` or `-` and downstream filters would have to process each row of the either `+` or `-` result set, thats near the worst case)

So far, we know that `txStart` has the most differentiated values distribution amongst the interesting columns of your query.

So, your query definitely should utilize an index query on that column! But a btree index, not a hash index (operators `<`, `<=`, `>` etc. are fast on btree, but not on hash).

Try again with just a single (btree) index on `txStart` (I know you already tried that, but please try again and avoid all secondary indexes etc..).

Multi column indexes are nice, but their complexity make them not as fast as plain single column indexes, MySQLs optimizer is rather stupid in selecting the optimal indexes ;-)

Another important factor *could* be the dynamic row size (because of using `longblob` columns). But I am not up-to-date on the current state of MySQL in that regard.

Comment: Thank you -- I appreciate your comment. My thought process was similar. I did try indexing on `txStart` again, and it was still significantly slower than others, the reasons for which are still beyond me...

Comment: | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |  
| 1 | SIMPLE | wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 | range | chrom,txStart | txStart | 4 | NULL | 1571 | Using where |

Comment: Is it significantly faster when you completely omit the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Yes. It would be great if finding the closest value can be achieved without using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Well, have you tried `SELECT chrom, txStart, txEnd, name2, strand
 FROM wgEncodeGencodeCompV12
 WHERE txStart=( SELECT MAX(txStart) FROM wgEncodeGencodeCompV12 WHERE chrom='chr1' AND txStart<713885 AND strand='+' )
 AND chrom='chr1' AND strand='+'` ?

Comment: .. and it could be optimized further if txStart (or chrom+txStart+strande) would be unique (your original query does only make sense if chrom+txStart+strand is unique anyway...)

Comment: This is indeed faster and has improved run time significantly. And yes, the `chrom + txStart + strand` combination should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The index that you want is:  `wgEncodeGencodeCompV12(chrom, strand, txstart)`.

In general, you want the fields with equalities as the first columns in the index.  Then add one field with the inequality.

Comment: Thank you -- that makes sense and did improve run time slightly.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say here?

Comment: `rows` is reduced to 57. The full output is in the main text (can't figure out how to format it right in the comment)